# Smart pointers in static code analysis

Tags: cppcheck

In our code, we are extensively using smart pointers for memory management. We are also using CPPCheck for static analysis.

I have noticed that CPPCheck can never find if there are any smart pointer related errors like null pointer check. Is there anyway we can force CPPCheck to look for such errors in the usage of our own locally defined smart pointers?

Comment: Currently cppcheck does not understand smart pointers. In order to convince the developers to implement checks regarding smart pointers, please create tickets at cppcheck-[bugtracker](http://trac.cppcheck.net/wiki).  Each ticket should consist of a small, compilable example where you describe the issue cppcheck should detect.